# How to use Scroll Lock key to browse through gnome-terminal's output?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

While using `gnome-terminal`, the only way to view output is to use the scroll bar on one of the sides of the emulator.

By default the arrow keys(<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>) are set to browse through history commands one by one.

I want to use <kbd>ScrLk⇓</kbd> with the arrow keys to browse through output rather than history(i.e when <kbd>ScrLk⇓</kbd> is inactive, arrow keys would browse through history and when <kbd>ScrLk⇓</kbd> is active, arrow keys would browse through output).

How do I do this?

> **NOTE:** By default, <kbd>ScrLk⇓</kbd> key is not detected by X and only detected by tty. So I made it detectable by using the following commands.
>
> - First checked the empty mod with,
>
>   > ```
>   > xmodmap -pm
>   > ```
> - Then assigned <kbd>ScrLk⇓</kbd> to empty mod 3,
>
>   > ```
>   > xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
>   > ```

Comment: I hope you are aware about Shift + PageUp and Shift + PageDown shortcuts to scroll the contents of terminal window.

Comment: That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Thanks! (*and* upvoted!)